# Netplan: give IPv6 priority over IPv4

Tags: ipv6, systemd-networkd, ipv4, priority, netplan

On a dual-stack workstation (single interface, Ubuntu 18.04), I'd like IPv6 to be chosen first, before IPv4.
I guess that means essentially to have domains being resolved first by DNS6, and then by DNS4.

In Netplan (renderer: networkd), is there a way to give "generally" more priority to IPv6, or, at least, to have DNS6 resolve before DNS4? (could it be as simple as the order of the nameservers?)